# Error when installing my own Chrome Extension from Chrome Web Store: "Download error: Could not unzip extension"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I'm developing a chrome extension, here is my [repo](https://github.com/debugtheworldbot/danmaku), after I finished a feature, I run script in package.json `pnpm surge` which is `npm version patch && tsc --noEmit && vite build && zip dist.zip -r dist` to create a build file and compress the dist dictionary to `dist.zip`, and submit this zip file to chrome web store.

At the earlier releases(I can't remember when), everything works fine, but in recent release, after my new submission is accepted and publish to store,I try to install it at the store, I got this  error `Download error: Could not unzip extension`, but load the same unpacked dist dictionary works just fine.

I search the net, but suggestions are vague, like resubmit the package with a bumped version. But this thing just happens randomly. Is there any way to debug what's going wrong? Or my code have some problem I can't figure out?

resubmit the zip file not 100% working

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Maybe there's a 0-sized file in zip?

Comment: I checked the zip, seems there is no 0-sized file...